# CX509PublicKeyClass initialize is failing at runtime with WIN32: 13 ERROR_INVALID_DATA

Tags: sdk, pkcs#11, ca

I am trying to populate the CX509PublicKeyClass() object using **InitializeFromEncodedPublicKeyInfo(data);** where data is from the file id_rsa.pub (**KeyFilePath**) that I created using ss-keygen client in windows.

Sample code I am tying with
[image]

The image also shows the exception that is being thrown.
I suspect the issue could be with the expected encoding

```
public virtual void InitializeFromEncodedPublicKeyInfo(string strEncodedPublicKeyInfo, EncodingType Encoding = EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64);
```

and I have tried multiple combinations, Hex and base64 , default string etc but I am still seeing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in understanding RSA key formats

1. Private key contains: modulus, private exponent, public exponent, prime 1, prime 2, exponent 1, exponent 2 and coefficient
2. Public key contains: only modulus and public exponent.

PEM format produced by OpenSSL is actually base64 encoded and wrapped key data in the binary format called DER. Thus, to work with PEM format you must actually work with DER.

DER format is based on Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1) standard. The standard specifies the encoding of tree-like data structures. Two predefined data structures are used for private and public RSA keys. Though I didn’t find a good parser for the format, with a couple of notes from the standard in hand I wrote a class for encoding and decoding ASN.1 values.

PEM format contains base64 encoded DER data. It also adds a header and footer to it. Below is an example of PEM file for a private key.

[image]